# How do I write this math symbol in Sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app, mathematics

How do I write any math symbol in Sketch 3? I want to write them in "text" if I can. If I can't, what else can I do besides of insert pictures?  Here are the pictures attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Try the Character Palette

If you can insert it via the OS X character palette, you're good.
Other than that, I'm not aware of any math plug-ins for Sketch.

[image: OS X's character palette, showing math symbols]

## Roll your own

One of Sketch's most lovable features is that [you can write plug-ins to do most of what you can dream up](http://developer.sketchapp.com/). Given math symbol support at the OS level, it seems feasible that a UI could be built to handle the input.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, I have tried to use Unicode (Character Palette) for some math equation, but it didn't work out. I believe it is better for basic math writing.

Comment: @BMWSLAMDUNK: not sure what you expected, then. The character palette shows what *characters* are available. It has nothing to do with 'equations'. The division in your examples, for example, is not a single "character" or "symbol".

Comment: @RadLexus  Hey, thanks for your reply. But I wonder that how can I type a neat and organized math (like the division in my example) in xcode, I was trying to write it in Sketch 3, then apply it to xcode, however, it is still hard to me to find a way.